# Eigen library - least squares

Tags: eigen, least-squares

I want to use a least squares problem with the use of Eigen library.
My options are 2,

- sysAAA.jacobiSvd( Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV ).solve( sysBBB )
- sysAAA.colPivHouseholderQr().solve( sysBBB );

I was using the first in the beginning, but it proved to be very slow (1)(2).

So I went to the second solution (other methods aren't appropriate for my case, because they require special matrices (2) )

Does colPivHouseholderQr().solve give a least squares solution?

My impression is that it doesn't (3), but I want to be sure before looking for a "workaround".

1. http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=102088
2. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html
3. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialLinearAlgebra.html#TutorialLinAlgLeastsquares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ColPivHouseholderQr::solve() computes a least-square solution.

Comment: Thank you very much ggael!
Do you maybe have a reference link that states it, to use it in future for similar questions?
I couldn't find something that states it clearly.

Comment: Just for the records, GGael gave a proof here http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=109604&p=257048#p257013

Thanx ggael!